# Deploying a Django Rest Framework that has some celery tasks to Docker throws a Celery ImportError in the container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, celery

I am working on a DRF project where I have some tasks being handled asynchronously by Celery tasks. Everything works perfectly when I don't deploy to docker but when I deploy to docker, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-03-20 21:51:09   File "/app/file_upload_service/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
2023-03-20 21:51:09     from .celery import app as celery_app
2023-03-20 21:51:09   File "/app/file_upload_service/celery.py", line 2, in <module>
2023-03-20 21:51:09     from celery import Celery
2023-03-20 21:51:09   File "/app/celery.py", line 2, in <module>
2023-03-20 21:51:09     from celery import Celery
2023-03-20 21:51:09 ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery' from partially initialized module 'celery' (most likely due to a circular import) (/app/celery.py)
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.10-alpine

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements file into the container at /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/


# Copy the Celery configuration file into the container
COPY ./file_upload_service/celery.py /app/

# Set the environment variable for the Celery command
ENV C_FORCE_ROOT=1


# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the entire application directory into the container at /app
COPY . /app/

# Expose port 8000
EXPOSE 8000

# Define environment variables
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=file_upload_service.settings

# Start the server
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - celery
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: file_upload_service
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - "./db:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
  redis:
    image: "redis"
    ports:
    - "6380:6379"
  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A file_upload_service worker  -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=file_upload_service.settings
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6380
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6380
```

and finally this is my celery.py:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "file_upload_service.settings"

from celery import Celery
import django
django.setup()

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "file_upload_service.settings")
app = Celery("file_upload_service")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

I'm not sure what could be causing the issue, could be because I am copying the celery file from the app directory to the root folder in the Dockerfile

Comment: `and finally this is my celery.py` Could that be causing the circular import? E.g. you do `from celery import Celery`, so it looks for a file named `celery.py`, and imports itself.

Comment: This was the issue. Renaming celery.py to something else solved the problem